how to create a site and proxy to serve large files fast with nginx?
II've been struggling with the configuration files for weeks, but I'm not able to reach a functional and satisfactory result for my needs, so I decided to try and ask for help here.
I need to create two nginx vhost files, one to serve an html website plus a txt file that needs to be read and provide a zip file for download
the other must act as a proxy, the client machine must connect through its IP and on port 8080, the objective is that when the connected client machine tries to make a request for a url that ends with list.txt, access is directed to the vhost on port 80 and the server's txt file is read instead of what is in the original url.
in turn, the txt file has another url that will be used to make another request that must also be directed to a zip file, I even managed at some point to make this work, but the download speed was terrible, the zip file has around 200mb, what would be the best approach to accomplish this with a satisfactory speed?
My last tests were with the two files below, but I can't get to the zip file, only the txt, could you give me some tips please?
Proxy file:
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/files levels=1:2 keys_zone=files:10m max_size=4g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

log_format proxy_log '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user "$host$request_uri" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'
' Proxy: "$proxy_host" "$upstream_addr"';

server {
  listen 8080;

  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location ~* /update/.*/(list\.txt|update\.zip)$ {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy_new_access.log proxy_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy_new_error.log;
    proxy_cache files;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/files/$1;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_buffers 32 4m;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64m;
    proxy_buffer_size 4m;
    proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    client_body_buffer_size 4m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
  }

}

site file:
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache_zone:10m max_size=10g inactive=1d use_temp_path=off;
log_format test 'site $remote_addr [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $request_body '
'"$http_referer" "$content_type" "$host" "$args" $realpath_root';
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name teste.site.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/teste.site.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/teste.site.com/privkey.pem;

  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log teste;

  location ~ ^/files/.*list\.txt$ {
    root /var/www/site/;
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~* ^/files/.*update\.zip$ {
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="update.zip"';
    sendfile on;
    root /var/www/site/;
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name teste.site.com;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;

  root /var/www/site;
  index index.html;

  include mime.types;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires 1d;
  }

  location ~ ^/files/.*list\.txt$ {
    root /var/www/site/;
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~* ^/files/.*update\.zip$ {
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="update.zip"';
    root /var/www/site/;
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
}

thanks!
